# What is the idiomatic way of embedding in Go (unlike classical-OOP)?

Tags: go, interface, embedding

I'm creating an e-commerce store and want to find out the most idiomatic way to structure my types.

I'm embedding the Game type because the other game types almost have the same set of fields and methods.

```golang
type GameDetails struct {
  Title string
  Price int
}

func (g *GameDetails) String() string {
  return g.Title
}

func (g *GameDetails) Tax(ratio float64) {
  g.Price = float64(g.Price) * ratio
}

// other Game methods...

type BoardGame struct {
  GameDetails
}

type OnlineGame struct {
  GameDetails
}

type VideoGame struct {
  GameDetails
  Genre string
}

func (g *OnlineGame) String() string {
  return g.Title +", "+ g.Genre
}
```

I'm representing the games in an interface so I can use them together:

```golang
type Game interface {
  String() string
  Tax(ratio float64)
}

func main() {
  games := []Game{
    &VideoGame{...},
    &BoardGame{...},
    &OnlineGame{...},
  }

  // ... print games to a user
}
```

I can easily marshal the games as JSON, and I'm implementing the `UnmarshalJSON` method in a concrete slice to get the concrete games back from JSON.

```golang
type Games []Game

func (g *Games) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  // ...
}
```

**My question is: Is this an idiomatic way to structure my code? What is the best way to structure my code using Go idioms?**

I feel like I'm building an inheritance hierarchy instead of composing. How to get away from my old OOP habits? Can you show me an example? What is wrong with this code?

I read other answers but people only say: "don't do that in Go, there is no inheritance" etc. I know that, but I couldn't find a good example to explain this in a code example.

---

For anyone reading this question, there are similar implementations in the [testing](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go) and [template](https://golang.org/src/text/template/parse/node.go) packages.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Embedding is nice syntactic sugar to make a composite and expose the method of the embedded type on the one embedding it. If this is an appropriate data model of your domain then this is fine. If not, then it is not. There is nothing "idiomatic" here. It either fits or doesn't. If GameDetails does not bring lots of method directly exposed on each Game it probably is not a good approach. If it is, it is. The String method of your OnlineGame "breaks" the clean embedding a bit. If this is the exception: It is fine.

Comment: Take a look at how `testing.T` and `testing.B` both embed `common`. This works nicely as both `T` and `B` can delegate a set of work to a `common` living inside them. This is not inheritance. Especially your example is not "inheritance like". You model polymorphism via a `Game` interface. Different implementations of `Game` hand several methods to a standalone `GameDetails`. To me this looks fine; at least if you do not have to reimplement lots if embedded methods on the embedding type.

Comment: Just a tip: I really wouldn't use a pointer receiver on my `String` functions. Those funcs will never modify the actual value anyway, and using value receivers make the types safe for concurrent use. With a pointer receiver, there's a chance of simultaneous write/read access to occur.

Comment: OnlineGame breaks it because it wants to print its own details, is there a better way? I'll take a look at the testing package, thanks for that!

Comment: Yes Elias, I'm aware but it's better to keep the receiver types consistent. Tax method needs to have a pointer receiver.